# Convert a MySQL Query to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a MySQL query that needs to be converted over to PostgreSQL. As I understand,  PostgreSQL has no UTC_TIMESTAMP() or DATE_ADD() functions available. After reading the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html), I'm not entirely certain which date functions solve my needs in this context.

Here's the query:

```
INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires)
VALUES(?, ?, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL ? DAY))
```

For reference, here is my snippets model:

```
CREATE TABLE snippets (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL,
    expires TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: The use of the non-standard serial types [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial). It's better to use the standard compliant `identity` columns with modern Postgres versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done much with postgresql either, but maybe something like:

```
INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires)
VALUES('test', 'stuff', (now() at time zone 'utc'), (now() at time zone 'utc' + interval '1 day' * 3))
```

Which gives:

```
id  title   content created             expires
1   test    stuff   2022-11-23 13:02:13 2022-11-26 13:02:13
```

Then to restore the parameterized version of the query:

```
INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires)
VALUES(?, ?, (now() at time zone 'utc'), (now() at time zone 'utc' + interval '1 day' * ?))
```

I was not sure how to test the parameterized equivalent, but here's a [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/o-4hF-9t) with the output from the first query.

Comment: Either `interval '1 day' * ?` or `make_interval(days => ?)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... thanks I've updated the answer (and the fiddle) with the first part of your suggestion.